# which sentence is correct when I speak about future?

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct and why is it correct?

> I'm sure he's going to win.
> I'm sure he will win.

another question, please:

a)Which one is correct and why is it correct?

1-Look at the dark clouds. I *****think*** it’s going to** rain.
2-look at the dark clouds. I *****think*** it will** rain.
3-Both of the above sentences are correct.

B)Which one is correct and why?

1-Look at the dark clouds. I'm *****sure*** it’s going to** rain.
2-look at the dark clouds. I'm *****sure*** it will** rain.
3-Both of the above sentences are correct.

Comment: Both are correct and mean the same thing.

Comment: I found it in an exam so it was a problem to me because I had the same opinion as you. how can it be solved then?

Comment: There is no single future tense in English. There are numerous constructions that are used to refer to the future. The problem lies with the examiner who may consider that only the use of **will** serves this purpose.

Comment: so then, he wants me to say "will" instead of  "be going", doesn't he?

Comment: What exactly was asked in the exam?

Comment: choose the correct : I'm sure he ------------ win. 1- will  2- is going to

Comment: and another confusing one.choose the correct: the weather forecast says it ------------ rain tomorrow. 1- will 2- is going to

Comment: These are very bad exam questions, because both options are perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: I agree that the exam questions are awful because any of the two options are appropriate. However, in *some* grammar books  there is the notion that "will" is better suited for expressing opinions, and "going to" for certainties. As in: "*I **think** (=I'm not 100% sure) he'll win*" and "*He's (definitely) **going to** win!*" when the person is **about to** cross the finishing line, or win the last point. Does "sure" in the examples refer to the speaker's opinion "think" or to something that is evidently true? Who knows? Were these questions made up by the teacher?

Comment: unfortunately, these questions were in an educational book. these questions had no any additional context, that's why I posed them.

Answer (score -1):

“is going to do” is considered informal by speakers and sloppy by teachers because we have a real future tense in “will do”, which is preferred in formal writing.

There is a subtle difference in intent vs commitment, but in practice the two are used interchangeably.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain why.

Comment: I know that "be going" is used in informal speaking instead of "will" but it also has usage in formal speaking and grammar.